# Dependency Injection With Generic Repository

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to do dependency injection (ASP.NET CORE) in my web api controller but I am having problems, since have a generic repository with unit of work, and also a generic service layer. The services are in a different class library. The same occurs for the repositories.

I am displaying my code:

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
   {
     private IAccountService _accountService;

   public AccountController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }
   }
```

service layer (base service):

```
  public class BaseService<TEntity> : IDisposable, IBaseService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IBaseRepository<TEntity> _repository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public BaseService(IBaseRepository<TEntity> repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

account service:

```
public class AccountService : BaseService<User>, IAccountService
{
    private readonly IAccountRepository _repository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public AccountService(IAccountRepository repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base (repository, unitOfWork)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

base repository:

```
  public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable, IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected NeoSpaceDbContext _database;

    public BaseRepository(NeoSpaceDbContext database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }
```

account repository:

```
public class AccountRepository : BaseRepository<User>, IAccountRepository
{
    public AccountRepository(NeoSpaceDbContext context) : base(context)
    {} 
}
```

I think my problem is my startup configuration in my web api.

I have already tried:

```
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseService<User>), typeof(AccountService));
```

and:

```
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseService<>), typeof(BaseService<>));
        services.AddSingleton<IAccountService, AccountService>();
```

but nothing works ...
Can someone tell me what is the right configuration for my case?

Comment: Can you add a tag to describe which DI framework you're using?

Comment: I just saw this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

I don't know what framework they are using @StriplingWarrior

Comment: From the linked article, "ASP.NET Core includes a simple built-in container (represented by the IServiceProvider interface) that supports constructor injection by default, and ASP.NET makes certain services available through DI." I'm guessing this "simple built-in container" is not complex enough to handle the kind of generic bindings you're trying to configure. Consider using a more fully-featured DI container. SimpleInjector and Ninject are popular options. Unity is backed by Microsoft.

Comment: What do your Interfaces look like. Are they just empty?

Comment: @Patrick Mcvay in this example it was empty,  but they have specific repository methods

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I am gonna check it out!

Comment: Have you found a solution after all these years?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont need to

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseService<>), typeof(BaseService<>));
```

because `IAccountService` should implement `IBaseService<>`
and AccountService should implement `BaseService<>`. so you should not need to resolve `IBaseService`

```
services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
```

should work